# Receiving undefined method `reflect_on_association' for NilClass:Class Cocoon Rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cocoon-gem

I'm currently using a double nested partial to add child records to a deeply nested form. The form inputs show, but the **link_to_add_association** button throws an exception. How can I reach the child form input with my link_to_add_association button?

**providers_controller.rb**

```
class ProviderContractsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_provider_contract, only: %i[show edit update destroy]

def new
    @provider_contract = ProviderForm.find(params[:provider_form_id])
    @provider_contract = ProviderContract.new(provider_form_id: @provider.id)
    @provider_contract.build_contract_term
    @provider_contract.contract_term.contract_term_fees.build


  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
    redirect_to home_path, notice: 'The provider has been removed or has not been selected'
  end

  private

  # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
  def set_provider_contract
    @provider_contract = ProviderContract.find(params[:id])
  end

  # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
  def provider_contract_params
    params.require(:provider_contract).permit(ProviderContract.attribute_names.map(&:to_sym),

                                              contract_term_attributes: ContractTerm.attribute_names.map(&:to_sym).push( contract_term_fees_attributes: ContractTermFee.attribute_names.map(&:to_sym).push(:id, :_destroy))
  end
end
```

**_form.html.erb**

```
 <%= simple_form_for(@provider_contract, html: { class: "ui form"}) do |f| %>
    <%= f.error_notification %>
    <%= f.error_notification message: f.object.errors[:base].to_sentence if f.object.errors[:base].present? %>

  <div class="ui tab" data-tab="stage-4">
      <%= f.simple_fields_for :contract_term do |ct| %>
        <%= render 'provider_contracts/partials/contract_term', f: ct %>
      <% end %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

**_contract_term.html.erb**

```
<div id="#term_fees">
    <%= f.simple_fields_for contract_term_fees do |ff| %>
      <%= render 'provider_contracts/contract_term_fee_fields', f: ff %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
  <div class="pt-2 pb-2 links">
    <%= link_to_add_association f, :contract_term_fees, class: 'ui positive basic button' do %>
      Add Fees
    <% end %>
  </div>
```

**contract_term.rb**

```
class ContractTerm < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :provider_contract
  has_many :contract_term_fees, dependent: :destroy


  accepts_nested_attributes_for :contract_term_fees, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
end
```

**Server Logs**

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `reflect_on_association' for NilClass:Class):
    62:     <% end %>
    63:   </div>
    64:   <div class="pt-2 links">
    65:     <%= link_to_add_association  f, :contract_term_fees, class: 'ui secondary basic button' do %>
    66:       Add Fees
    67:     <% end %>
    68:   </div>
```

Comment: The error shows some code that's not on the code you are showing (line 65 on the error is not the same on your contract_term_fees partial).

Comment: My apologies, I was exhausted last night.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the problem, but you are missing the `:` here `<%= f.simple_fields_for contract_term_fees do |ff| %>`, `:contract_terms_fees`

Answer (score 1):

In general when this error occurs, it means that either an `accepts_nested_attributes_for` is missing, or that somewhere we hand in a nil object.

From the code you show, either

- the `accepts_nested_attributes_for :contract_terms` is missing in `Contract` ?
- the `f.simple_fields_for contract_term_fees` is a typo and should read `f.simple_fields_for :contract_term_fees` (`contract_term_fees` is obviously nil)

Note in Rails 6 as in Rails 5, you will also have to declare the `inverse_of:` of a relation to make sure the nested relations will save correctly (as a `belongs_to` is by default required, and without the `inverse_of` rails has no way of knowing it was provided).

So

```
  belongs_to :provider_contract, inverse_of: :contract_terms
```

Comment: The provider form id wasn't being saved..I simply put it in a hidden field

Comment: Thanks! - I'll use inverse_of from now on